# Is it possible to use special characters with TCPDF library?

Tags: fonts, tcpdf, truetype

I'm using a font that contains some special character such as old style figures. Is there any way to specify that these should be used instead of regular numbers?

Comment: Those are called "OpenType features".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts need to be converted into the format used by TCPDF. The [`addTTFfont()`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF_FONTS/#_addTTFfont) method can be used to convert the supported font types. More information on conversion is [available here](https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/).

After the font is converted you can set it as the current font using the [`SetFont()`](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_SetFont) method.

If the special numbers you want to use are assigned to a different character, then you will need to replace the characters in your strings before printing the strings to the PDF.

Comment: An OpenType feature only has to be enabled to do precisely that, automatically. It also can replace mapped glyphs with *unmapped* glyphs – your wording suggests tcpdf cannot do that. Is that correct?

Comment: I’m not familiar with OpenType features. The `addTTFfont()` method can convert fonts in the OpenType format. However, I’m not sure what that means for its support of OpenType features.

Comment: Adam, then it's most likely that OpenType features are not supported at all. (They are horribly difficult to implement properly, and if tcpdf *did* support any of them, they'd surely mention it...) More bad news: it is customary – often even straight out recommended – to "store" alternates into unassigned glyphs, rather than with a unique character code of their own. Still, the OP may be lucky: not all font designers do so.

Comment: Thank you @AdamMoller and @usr2564301 - I've already converted the font and able to use it with `SetFont()` method but not able to find any way to use the OpenType characters. Will post an update here if I have any progress.